# Android multiple sound files

Tags: android, flash, audio, mp3

I am designing a foreign language app for android. When a word is clicked on or rolled over I would like the word to sound without opening a different window. Each chapter of the book will have approx 50 different words and have about 10 chapters. The book is pretty much finished (dreamweaver/jquery) but I have no experience programming android apps. I had it working fine in flash, but android 4 does not support this. Any plain speaking help to get multi-audio files working would be gratefully received.
Many thanks in advance,
John Q